# ElasticSearch: Highlights every word in phrase query

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I get Elastic Search to only highlight words that caused the document to be returned?

I have the following index

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "document": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "english": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "english"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let say I have indexed:

> Nuclear power is the use of nuclear reactions that release nuclear
>   energy[5] to generate heat, which most frequently is then used in
>   steam turbines to produce electricity in a nuclear power station. The
>   term includes nuclear fission, nuclear decay and nuclear fusion.
>   Presently, the nuclear fission of elements in the actinide series of
>   the periodic table produce the vast majority of nuclear energy in the
>   direct service of humankind, with nuclear decay processes, primarily
>   in the form of geothermal energy, and radioisotope thermoelectric
>   generators, in niche uses making up the rest.

And search for "nuclear elements"~2

I only want "nuclear fission of elements" or parts of "nuclear fission of elements" to be highlighted but every single occurrence of nuclear is now highlighted.

This is my query if it helps:

```
{
  "fields": [
  ],
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "\"nuclear elements\"~2",
      "fields": [
        "content.english"
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "<em class='h'>"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "</em>"
    ],
    "fragment_size": 500,
    "number_of_fragments": 20,
    "fields": {
      "content.english": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this on ES 1.7 and ES 2.0, what version of ES you are using?

Comment: I tried to reinstall ES and are still having the same issue. I am using 2.1.1 with lucene_version 5.3.1. Did you create the same index and use the same query?

Comment: I think this could be related to [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15291), This is the [PR](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/15516), which has been merged. I think it should give correct results with 2.1.2 and 2.2.0

Comment: If possible, try with some other version so that you will know for sure if it is indeed a bug.

Comment: Thank you. It works with an older version. Do you want to answer this as an "answer" so that I can give you the correct answer?

Comment: glad, you figured out. I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [highlighting bug](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15291) in ES 2.1, which was caused due to [this change](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/13239). This has been fixed by this [Pull Request](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/15516).

According to ES developer

> This is a bug that I introduced in #13239 while thinking that the
>   differences were due to changes in Lucene: extractUnknownQuery is also
>   called when span extraction already succeeded, so we should only fall
>   back to Weight.extractTerms if no spans have been extracted yet.

It works in older versions till 2.0 and would work as expected in future versions.

Comment: using Elasticsearch 7.1, still highlights per word, not per **PHRASE** :(