# highlight does not properly work with exact phrase match search in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having problem with highlighting the exact phrase search. when the highlight comes back it highlights all the terms regardless of the exact search. see the example:

```
Put /test2
PUT /test2/all/1
{
  "name" :         "climate behaviour change"
}
PUT /test2/all/3
{
  "name" :         "climate behaviour change it is climate change"
}
```

and my mapping:

```
{
  "test2": {
    "mappings": {
      "all": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and when I run this query:

```
GET /test2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["name"],
      "query": "\"climate change\""

 }
}
    ,"highlight": {
            "fields": {
            "name": {"number_of_fragments": 0}
                }
    }
}
```

the result is

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test2",
        "_type": "all",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.23013961,
        "_source": {
          "name": "climate behaviour change it is climate change"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "name": [
            "<em>climate</em> behaviour <em>change</em> it is <em>climate</em> <em>change</em>"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

since I searched for exact climate change I would expect to have highlight for just the second part of the result, so climate behaviour change should not get highlighted. Does anyone know why this is like that?
or any other way I can get what I want?

Comment: what version of ES you are using?

Comment: I tried the above query .worked fine for me. Can you please share the mapping. GET /test2/all/_mapping

Comment: @Richa mapping added to the post

Comment: there is a bug in 2.1, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643781/elasticsearch-highlights-every-word-in-phrase-query you might want to upgrade.

Comment: @ChintanShah25 I have tried 2.0.2 and works fine with that version. could not find the debian package for later version than 2.1.1, is there any?
another issue with 2.0.2 was that my current kibana version does not work with this version.

Comment: Oh, I guess latest is 2.1.1 only, you need kibana 4.2 with 2.0 and 4.3 with 2.1.x.

Answer (score 0):

By Default `query_string` uses `OR` operator [see here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-top-level-params)

Rather use `AND` operator.

```
GET /test2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["name"],
      "query": "\"climate change\"",
      "default_operator": AND

 }
}
    ,"highlight": {
            "fields": {
            "name": {"number_of_fragments": 0}
                }


    }
}
```