# "match_phrase" hit with no highlights returned

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index that includes the full text of different books belonging to a specific series.  Each document represents a different volume in a series, and each volume has a set of nested documents on it corresponding to a section of text in that book.  This is the query we are using in order to get highlights matching a specific phrase within all the books of a given series:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 3,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "sections.content.phrase": {
                        "query": "theory legal",
                        "type": "phrase",
                        "slop": X
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "path": "sections",
            "inner_hits": {
              "highlight": {
                "order": "score",
                "fields": {
                  "sections.content.phrase": {}
                }
              },
              "_source": {
                "include": [
                  "title",
                  "id"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "series": "00410"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Normally this query works fine, but for some series we can get hits in books with no highlighted text returned.  For example with the above phrase query, series, and a slop value of 1 we correctly get a single hit for one book in the series: `(each allegation of discrimination or each <em>theory</em> of <em>legal</em> recovery not required to be set forth in separate`.  If we take the same query and up the slop value to 3 we suddenly get hits in 5 different books each with no matching highlights found.  Not even the original hit from when the slop value was 1 is returned.  Why are we getting these results?

Comment: My best guess is that you are using ES 2.1 and there is a bug in that, have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643781/elasticsearch-highlights-every-word-in-phrase-query/34664420#34664420)

Comment: We're using 2.3.5 so that could be it as it seems to be using the same lucene version.

Comment: I don't think it is due to lucene version. You might want to raise an [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues)

Comment: Going to do that now, tested with the 5.0-rc and it still returns no highlights.